# passing tokens from array to strcmp

Tags: c, arrays, string, delimiter, tcc

What I am trying to do is to break the user input in parts with whitespace as a delimiter, copy the parts into the array (`tokenAr`) and compare the `tokenAr[0]` (the first part) if it is equal to `sHistory`. if they are equal, check the value of `tokenAr[1]` if it is "1", "2" etc, to execute the corresponding command that is entered in the `history` array. This is what i have tried to far and it crashes. I am using TCC on Windows x64.
EDIT: I forgot to mention that I began learning C, just two days ago.

EDIT2: I run the program in a debugger and it has raised an `Acces Violation(Segmentation Fault)` in line `if(strcmp(tokenArPtr[0],sHistory)==0)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int i=1; int j=1; int k=0;
    char history[100][100] = {0};
    char sKey[] = "exit";
    char sInput[100];
    char sHistory[]="history";

    do 
    {
        //gather user input
        printf ("hshell> ");
        fgets (sInput, 100, stdin);
        strcpy(history[i],sInput);
        i++;
        //END_gather user input

        //Tokenizing

        char delims[] = " ";
        char *tokenArPtr[5];
        char *result = NULL;

        result = strtok(sInput, delims);
        tokenArPtr[0] = result;

        while (result!=NULL)
        {
              puts(result);
              result= strtok(NULL, delims);
              tokenArPtr[k+1] = result;

              puts(tokenArPtr[k]);
              puts("=====");
              k++;
        }
         k=0;
        /*
        //END_Tokenizing

        if(strcmp(tokenArPtr[0],sHistory)==0)
        {   
            for(j=1;j<i;j++)
            {
                printf("%d. %s \n",j,history[j]);
            }
        }

        else if (strcmp (sKey,tokenArPtr[0]) != 0)
        {
            printf("\nCommand not found \n");
        }*/
     }while (strcmp (sKey,sInput) != 0);  
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 3: I used the `result` variable instead of the `tokenArPtr` directly, but when debugging, I noticed that the values of the array are not being updated.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No. @hmjd should i set `k=0` after it exits the while loop? (just before the end_tokenizing comment)

Answer (score 0):

Which type does strtok return? `char *`. What is the type of tokenAr[k]? `char`. What type does strcmp expect as input? `char *` and `char *`. What is the type of tokenAr[0]? `char`.

See a problem? You should. The `*` is pretty significant.

Assuming tokenAr is declared like `char *tokenAr[2];`, how many `char *` values can tokenAr store? What happens when k exceeds 2? You need to ensure you don't overflow your tokenAr array.

`history` is uninitialised. Using an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour. I suggest initialising it, like this: `char history[100][100] = { 0 };`

Which book are you reading?

Comment: Edited the code according to your suggestion.  Lets say it will never exceed two, for simplicity's sake. Still crashing. I am reading Head First C.

Comment: `k++` followed by the test `tokenArPtr[k]!=NULL` is undefined behaviour, because tokenArPtr[k] is uninitialised. I would expect that to crash. Consider: `for (k = 0; k < sizeof tokenArPtr / sizeof *tokenArPtr; k++) { tokenArPtr[k] = strtok(NULL, delims); if (tokenArPtr[k] == NULL) { break; } }`

Comment: I will edit the code with my most recent changes that dont crash, but as you will see, I cannot update the array values. Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

While tokenizing, the loop will never end because the test is on the variable "result" that will never change... So you're finally going to a buffer overflow with "tokenAr"... Modify your code to test "tokenAr".

Edit: And tokenAR should be an array... (I don't know how it can compile...)

Comment: did it, but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems... First of all you should include string.h which will show you some errors in compilation.

I believe that the main problem is here:

```
    char tokenAr[2];
        result = strtok(sInput, delims);
        while (result!=NULL)
        {
                tokenAr[k] = strtok(NULL, delims);
                k++;
        }
```

tokenAr should be an array of pointers, not chars. And are you sure that k will never exceed 2? An assertion would help debugging.

Comment: You didn't remove the bug... You still check a constant value... You have to check the last written pointer